# error "an integer is requried" when converting to hex string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert c_uint to hex string, but getting errors:

```
x = c_uint(1083113632)
y = hex(x)
```

error: hex(QTestStream): argument 1 has unexpected type c_ulong

when trying:

```
z = ctypes.c_uint(x).value
t = hex(z)
```

error: TypeError: an integer is requried

I searched for similar solutions, but didn't found the right one.

how can I convert the c_uint to hex string ?

Answer (score 0):

Close, you need to call the `value` attribute on the `c_uint` object itself like so:

```
x = c_uint(1083113632)
y = hex(x.value)
print(y)
```

Comment: I'm getting hex(QTextStream): argument 1 has unexpected type long